HDF5 simple dataset only writing half of the elements
I have a larger data conversion utility this is a small piece of. It converts from an old format to memory, then writes memory to an HDF5 based output format. Below is a function, WriteFloatDataset, that as described, writes a float dataset. The first few lines show how it is called. It is writing the first half of the lines (always half) correctly, then garbage for the rest. The specification calls for floats rather than doubles. I have the double equivalent of this, and a character string version as well, work like a charm.
Update: code below has been updated with fix and other suggestions
...
    float* fArray = new float[ ppArrayCount ];
    for ( i = 0; i < ppArrayCount; i++ ) fArray[ i ] = this->ppArray[ i ].maop;
    MyDataset::WriteFloatDataset( fileid, dataspace, "/data/", "MAOP", fArray );
...


void MyDataset::WriteFloatDataset( 
   hid_t fileid,
   hid_t dataspace,
   const char* group,
   const char* name,
   float data[] )
{
   // HDF5 file and datagroup sized to arrayCountx1 should be open prior to calling
// This line was the problem, sizeof( H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT ) is 8, sizeof (float) is 4
//   hid_t datatype = H5Tcreate( H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof( H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT ) );
   hid_t datatype = H5Tcreate( H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof( float ) );
   H5Tinsert( datatype, name, 0, H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT );

   char datasetName[ TEMP_BUF_LEN ];
   
   strcpy_s( datasetName, TEMP_BUF_LEN, group );
   strcat_s( datasetName, TEMP_BUF_LEN, name );

   hid_t dataset = H5Dcreate( fileid, datasetName, datatype, dataspace, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
   H5Dwrite( dataset, datatype, dataspace, dataspace, H5P_DEFAULT, ( ( const void* )data ) );
   
   H5Dclose( dataset );
   H5Tclose( datatype );
}


As mentioned, this very similar function works great, it is something about the data type.
void POF110Dataset::WriteDoubleDataset(
   hid_t fileid,
   hid_t dataspace,
   const char* group,
   const char* name,
   double data[] )
{
   // HDF5 file and datagroup sized to arrayCountx1 should be open prior to calling
   hid_t datatype = H5Tcreate( H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof( double ) );
   H5Tinsert( datatype, name, 0, H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE );

   char datasetName[ TEMP_BUF_LEN ];

   strcpy_s( datasetName, TEMP_BUF_LEN, group );
   strcat_s( datasetName, TEMP_BUF_LEN, name );

   hid_t dataset = H5Dcreate( fileid, datasetName, datatype, dataspace, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT );
   H5Dwrite( dataset, datatype, dataspace, dataspace, H5P_DEFAULT, ( ( const void* )data ) );

   H5Dclose( dataset );
   H5Tclose( datatype );
}


It occurred to be to try H5T_IEEE_F32LE instead of H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT. If that fixes it, I will answer my own question. Otherwise, any advice appreciated.

The change from H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT to H5T_IEEE_F32LE did not resolve the issue.

This is an experiment:
 float* fArray = new float[ ppArrayCount * 2 ];
 for ( i = 0; i < ppArrayCount * 2; i++ ) fArray[ i ] = i * 1.0f;
 MyDataset::WriteFloatDataset( fileid, dataspace, "/data/", "MAOP", fArray );

Result was an array: 0.0, 2.0, 4.0, etc.

General reminder to check the documentation to ensure that the str*_s functions actually do what you want them to do. A lot of people use them thinking they're a safer alternative without knowing how they work and what they really do. Side note: avoid the magic numbers. It really sucks if someone changes a few, but not all, of those 256s.

You need to provide a minimal reproducible example. That includes the creation of the dataspace. Also, don't use the H5T_IEEE types, neither for double nor float, for the in-memory types. Use H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT and _DOUBLE. HDF5 translates the types automatically to the proper IEEE type. That way, the code is portable. For example your code would break on IBM Power-PC where the native type is big endian, H5T_IEEE_F32BE.

@user4581301 - I am usually good about not using magic numbers, though in this case they were local. The str*_s functions worked exactly as intended, but I dispelled the magic.

This is wrong:
hid_t datatype = H5Tcreate( H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof( H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT ) );

specifically the sizeof( H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT ). You are supposed to give HDF5 the size of the compound struct. You specify the size of the hid_t type for the H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT global constant.
In the double case it accidentally works because sizeof(double) == sizeof( H5T_NATIVE_DOUBLE ) on your system.
You can also see your mistake in the screenshots when you look at the Storage field. Both are 64464 bytes, even though both have the same logical dimensions while one stores 32 bit and the other one 64 bit.
Change it to sizeof(float) and sizeof(double), respectively, if that is all you want to store. Normally, its use would be like
struct CompoundType {
    float x;
    int y;
};
hid_t datatype = H5Tcreate( H5T_COMPOUND, sizeof( CompoundType ) );


Thank you, I don't know why I presumed the sizeof( H5T_NATIVE_FLOAT ) would match sizeof( float ), which are 8 and 4 on my system.
